# Xcode debugger displays NO for BOOL value that is 0x01

Tags: xcode, gdb

Argh, I hit a really weird problem.

I have a breakpoint set, and I'm trying to inspect a BOOL value. The summary in the locals section says clearly that it is NO. However, I'm pretty sure that the paramater passed in should have evaluated to YES.

So, I hovered my mouse over the variable in question and get the following screen, where the value is 0x01, and the summary says it is NO. (screen attached for your amusement).

What is going on here?
[image]

Comment: I think I got the same issue, its atleast very wierd. Is always like this.

![SCREENSHOT](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/11300725/boolbug.png).

Comment: Have the same issue - I will start a bounty ...

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/324127-xcode-debugger-confused-about-bool-values.html)?

Comment: Have you tried `NSLog(@"%c", menuGestureEnable);`?

Comment: weird really weird. Lets hope that apple will take care of it on the next update....

Comment: Can we see the code that should have evaluated to YES?

Answer (score 0):

I have reported this bug to Apple and this is the work-around (solution) that works by me:

> Right click on the variable in the Variables View and select **"Edit
>   Summary Format…"**.  Do you see the string "NO" in there?  If so, delete
>   that.